# Error - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building a sample app that lets users create a collection of "Word Groups" that contain multiple "Word Lists" which in turn contains multiple "Custom Words"

```
  #Word groups, word lists, and custom words
  resources :word_groups, shallow: true do
    resources :word_lists, shallow: true do
      resources :custom_words
    end
  end
```

My relevant routes -

```
word_group_word_lists GET    /word_groups/:word_group_id/word_lists(.:format)     word_lists#index
                      POST   /word_groups/:word_group_id/word_lists(.:format)      word_lists#create
```

/word_groups/index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.word_groups.any? %>
    <ol class="word_groups">
        <%= render @word_groups %>
    </ol>   
<% end %>
```

/word_groups/_word_group.html.erb

```
<li>
    <span class="name panel-body"><%= word_group.name %></span>
    <span class="name panel-body"><%= word_group.id %></span>
    <span class="name panel-body"><%= link_to "Manage Lists", word_group_word_lists_path(word_group)  %></span>
</li>
```

Both word_group.name and word_group.id return the right values.

The word_group_word_lists_path errors out with - "Error - No route matches {:controller=>"word_lists", :word_group_id=>#}"

I sincerely appreciate any help you can provide!

**UPDATE -**

I added a condition to check if the word_group is not nil and not_new in my view and that resolved it.

```
<% if !word_group.nil? && !word_group.new_record? %>
    <li>
        <span class="name panel-body"><%= word_group.name %></span>
        <span class="name panel-body"><%= link_to "Manage Lists", word_group_word_lists_path(word_group)  %></span>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These routes look right and this seems like it should work. Perhaps try to explicitly call the id in the path like this:

```
word_group_word_lists_path(word_group.id)
```

Comment: Thanks @benjaminjosephw. I tried that too and I get the following "No route matches {:controller=>"word_lists", :word_group_id=>nil}"

Comment: and `word_group.id` is definitely returning an integer?

Comment: also, I know this is obvious, but worth checking since I can't see what else could be wrong - have you restarted the rails server?

Comment: Finally, got this to work. Fired up the rails console, and when I did app.word_group_word_lists_path(1), it seemed to work. So I added a condition to check if the word_group is not nil and not new and this got it working.  Thank you @benjaminjosephw. Your note about everything being in order got me thinking that it was something minor.